# SSRS - Data Driven Subscription -

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

**What I'm trying to do**:
I have a report already created that looks for something existing in one database and not in another.  99% of the time the report comes up empty.  We do not need to know when there are no results to show.  I only want to know when the query returns a result.

**What I've done so far**:
I have a the Data Source created and a table (view) created to where I can query for Subscriber information.

**What I hope can be answered**:
Is it all possible to have this report run and email my selected Subscribers only when there is data in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've already looked into [Data-Driven subscriptions](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=ssrs%20data%20drive&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=ssrs%20data%20driven%20subscription&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.1.569110...........0.ojuYvFG3zRM).  You should be able to write your query in the data-driven subscription to test if the report should return results, and if not, send it to a dummy address, and only send it to your subscriber list if there will be data in it.

If you put the dummy address in your table with an IsDummy flag column, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT [EmailTo] 
FROM SubscriptionTable
WHERE IsDummy=0
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable)>0 --report should have results
UNION ALL
SELECT [EmailTo] 
FROM SubscriptionTable
WHERE IsDummy=1
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable)=0 --report should not have results
```

And that's only one way, there are probably lots of other ways that might suit your needs as well or better.

Comment: Trying this... Stay tuned.  Thank you!

Comment: We have monster success with this.  Thank you, thank you, thank you.